# Minimization of the squared difference of a generalized quadratic form and a given number

Tags: eigenvalues-eigenvectors, convex-optimization, nonlinear-optimization, quadratic-forms, quadratic-programming

For $i,j\in [n]$, let $\alpha_{ij}\in\mathbb{R}$ be given. Consider the function $F:\mathbb{R}^d\times\cdots\times\mathbb{R}^d\to\mathbb{R}$ defined by 
$$
F(x_1,\cdots,x_n) = \sum_{i = 1}^n\sum_{j = 1}^n \alpha_{ij}(x_i,x_j) 
$$
where $(x_i,x_j)$ denotes the standard inner product of $x_i$ and $x_j$ in $\mathbb{R}^d$. I call this kind of function a **generalized quadratic form** since, if $d = 1$, the function is exactly a quadratic form. In fact, letting $A = [\alpha_{ij}]_{n\times n}$ and $S = (A+A^T)/2$, $F(x_1,\cdots,x_n)$ may be written compactly as $F(x_1, \cdots, x_n) = \text{tr}(XSX^T)$, where $X$ is the $d\times n$ matrix formed by putting $x_1,\cdots,x_n$ as its columns. My question is: given a fixed number, say $\alpha\in\mathbb{R}$, how do I solve
$$
\min_{x_1,\cdots,x_n\in\mathbb{R}^d} (F(x_1,\cdots,x_n)-\alpha)^2
$$
and how do I find $x_1,\cdots,x_n$ that achieve the minimum? For my purpose, we may assume $S$ constructed above is positive semi-definite but I am also curious about the general situation. I am wondering whether this problem can be solved by playing with eigenvalues and eigenvectors of $S$. Any useful comments or direction to literature/topics would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that $F'_{x_j}=2\sum_{i=1}^{n}a_{ij}x_i$. In general, $F'=tr(2XS)$. You can use this derivates to find the extreme points of $(F-\alpha)^2$. You need to solve

$$2(-\alpha+\sum_{i=1}^{n}\sum_{j=1}^{n} a_{ij}x_i x_j)(2\sum_{i=1}^{n}a_{ij}x_i)=0\quad\forall j \in 1...n$$

Check this counts, please. Probably, you will need to use the Newton's Method to solve It. In addition, check this related question

[Multivariate Quadratic Regression](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3155866/multivariate-quadratic-regression)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I did try to compute the gradient and set it to zero. It seems that setting $2\sum_{i = 1}^n a_{ij}x_i=0, j = 1, ..., n$ would give me a system of linear equations. But what if I set the first part to zero? How do I solve it?

Comment: you need to find the solutions of $$\nabla (F(x_1, ..., x_n)-\alpha)^2 = 0$$  then I suppose there are many other solutions. You need to solve $$ 2(-\alpha+\sum_{i=1}^{n}\sum_{j=1}^{n} a_{ij}x_i x_j)(2\sum_{i=1}^{n}a_{ij}x_i)=0\quad\forall j \in 1...n $$ rather than $$ 2\sum_{i = 1}^n a_{ij}x_i=0, j = 1, ..., n $$. Try to solve by parts $$ 2(-\alpha+\sum_{i=1}^{n}\sum_{j=1}^{n} a_{ij}x_i x_j) =0 \quad\forall j \in 1...n $$ or $$ (2\sum_{i=1}^{n}a_{ij}x_i)=0\quad\forall j \in 1...n $$. Probably, you need to use numerical methods.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I think there is no changing $j$ for $2(-\alpha+\sum_{i = 1}^n\sum_{j = 1}^n a_{ij}x_ix_j) = 0$ since $j$ is already in the summation. Also, this equation is a degree 2 polynomial equation. It feels like a codimension 1 algebraic variety and I am not sure how numerics could solve it. I do notice the active field of "polynomial system solving". Maybe I will find some notes and figure something out. Thanks anyway.

Comment: You can use Newton's Method. For algebric approach, I think that you need to learn grobner basis. I prefer numerical methods.